# Winsock; Do I need to close a socket before reconnecting it?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock

I'm using winsock and I open my sockets in the standard way (I handle errors correctly, but for the sake of this question I've made the code brief);

```
SOCKET sSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

If I then connect it like so, it may lose connection occasionally.

```
connect(sSocket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&sinAddr), sizeof(sinAddr));
```

When this happens, do I need to close and re-create the socket, or should I just re-call connect() ?

Comment: will the socket connect to a different endpoint or the same endpoint?

Comment: The same server/host, the socket itself won't have changing settings.

Comment: TCP sockets (which you're using) once connected do not need reconnect. But if you must reconnect, you must(good practice) close this socket and then call connect()

Comment: Do I need to call socket() again though to re-create it..?

Comment: No you don't need to create the socket again.

Comment: @Aniket: If the socket had been closed it can not be used anymore, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a socket has been `close()`ed, it can not be used anymore.

Or the other way round: As long as `close()` has not been called on a socket, it can be (re-)used.

The call to `socket()` allocates a socket descriptor to the calling process. The socket descriptor exists and stays assigned to the process until `close()` is called.